# How to move several armatures at the same time using Follow Path constrains just changing one of theirs offset

Tags: animation

I have two armatures.

I used follow path on one of them as bone constrains attached to a curve.

When I change offset of follow path this armature moves as it is supposed to be moving. Following path.

Then I select other armature and then the armature I added constrain and used copy to selected in follow path constrains drop down menu. Now the other armature have the same path to follow and if you select it and
change offset it moves with the shape of this path.

But what I want to achieve is move both armatures with curve shape when I change only one of their offset.

---

Well, after selecting all armatures hold pressing option button (for Mac) and change offset with mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Empty with a <kbd>Follow Path</kbd> constraint pointing to your curve, then add both <kbd>Copy Location</kbd> and <kbd>Copy Rotation</kbd> constraints to each armature with the Empty as the target for all the constraints. That way you just have to change the offset of the constraint on the Empty and the armatures will change too without having to change individual offsets on each armature.